# Maven build excluding all files rather than java files

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I have created a maven project using `maven-archetype-quickstart` artifact. And got a directory structure like this :

```
my-app
+src
++main
+++java
++++com
+++++mycompnay
++test
```

Now, the problem is, when I put a file in java folder which is not a `*.java` files it is not getting included in the jar file after executing `mvn clean install`.

Here is the directory structure after adding those files using `jar tf target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`:

```
my-app
+src
++main
+++java
++++com
+++++mycompnay
++++++app
+++++++Blabla.java
+++++++Blabla.properties
++test
```

Here is the content of the jar file in target folder :

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/mycompany/
com/mycompany/app/
com/mycompany/app/Blabla.class
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.mycompany.app/
META-INF/maven/com.mycompany.app/my-app/
META-INF/maven/com.mycompany.app/my-app/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/com.mycompany.app/my-app/pom.properties
```

How can I include the properties file in the jar?

Answer (score 1):

### Prefered solution

Create a `resources` directory as shown in [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and replicate the same directory structure of `src/main/java` and put files there in there respective directory. In your case it will look like this :

```
my-app
+src
++main
+++resources
++++com
+++++mycompnay
++++++Blabla.properties
+++java
++++com
+++++mycompnay
++++++Blabla.java
++test
```

### Quick solution

Open the project pom.xml and add these lines :

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

It is telling to include `*.properties` files within `src/main/java` directory and leave anything rather than `*.properties` and `*.java`. **But this is not standard and hence not suggested.**

---

After applying any of the solution contents of jar file will look like this :

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/mycompany/
com/mycompany/app/
com/mycompany/app/Blabla.class
com/mycompany/app/Blabla.properties
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.mycompany.app/
META-INF/maven/com.mycompany.app/my-app/
META-INF/maven/com.mycompany.app/my-app/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/com.mycompany.app/my-app/pom.properties
```

If we are interested about why it is including the files in the resource folder we need to consult with `super pom`. All `pom.xml` inhertis from this pom. We can see a `<resource>` tag in `super pom`:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

It tells maven to include everything from resource directory.